# Get type of UIScrollView inside UIScrollViewDelegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIViewController` that has `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`. I want to do certain tasks when `UICollectionView` is scrolled.

I've extended `UIScrollViewDelegate` and wrote my code in

`func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`

But this method is called when both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` are scrolled. How do I differentiate between the two views here? I tried

```
  func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if let cv = scrollView as? UICollectionView {

    }
  }
```

But it's not working. I tried `po scrollView` and the output is  `<uninitialized>`.

Comment: How is your attempt now working? Did you set the `delegate` to `self`?

Comment: `delegate` on `UICollectionView`? I haven't set that delegate specifically but the delegate methods are called on both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`

Comment: How's that possible? How do you know the delegate methods are called? If they are called, how do you know your `if let` statement doesn't work?

Comment: I've set breakpoints in the `delegate` methods, if I remove the `if` statement the code inside is executed on both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` scrolling.

Comment: All you have to do is use the `isKind` protocol with fast enumeration.

Comment: Both TableView & CollectionView are subclasses of UIScrollView , that's why method gets called in both cases. Now to check whether its tableview or collectionView , simply checkyour tableview or collectionview instance against the scrollview instance you get inside ScrollViewDidScroll Method.

Answer (score 1):

// Say tv and cv are outlets to table View and Collection View

**Objective c**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.tv) {
        self.tv.contentOffset = self.tv.contentOffset;
    } else if (scrollView == self.cv) {
        self.cv.contentOffset = self.cv.contentOffset;
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if let scrollView == tv {
         //do whatever you need with tableView
    }
    if let scrollView == cv {
        //do whatever you need with collectionView
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake on my end but for others here I'll post the answer.

I needed to execute my code when slider has finished dragging/scrolling. To achieve that I had

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
    perform(#selector(UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)
}
```

Problem was in line

```
perform(#selector(UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)
```

Instead of passing nil, I wrote

```
perform(#selector(UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation), with: scrollView afterDelay: 0.3)
```

and that resolved it. I wasn't getting `scrollView` `<uninitialized>` anymore and my

```
if let cv = scrollView as? UICollectionView {

}
```

worked fine.